# GPS location of peoples using same product in 100 radius miles using Google map API

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, google-maps-api-2

Is it possible to find out gps location of peoples using same product in particular radius using Google map api in ios application?

Comment: I am using mCruiseOn (shameless self promotion) Open API's for locating cabs in the vicinity. I guess you can use the same api's to locate app launches. Should be easy to implement. You wont need to implement the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would need to write a web service that you post a request to containing a device token and coordinates. The server will maintain a table of device tokens and coords and return a list of devices for devices that google api determines as being within a given distance.