# How can i get all locations within 30 meter radius of my current location ios

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, reverse-geocoding

For my project, I want to find/drop pins on nearby location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971128/gps-location-of-peoples-using-same-product-in-100-radius-miles-using-google-map, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195341/objective-c-search-locations-with-radius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
CLLocationDistance radius = 30;
CLLocation* target = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:someLat longitude:someLon];


NSArray *locationsWithinRadius = [locations objectsAtIndexes:
                                 [locations indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
                                  ^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

                                      return [(CLLocation*)obj distanceFromLocation:target] < radius;

                                  }]];

[target release];
```

Comment: I need all nearby locations latitude, longitude. How can i get list of  all latitude and longitude.